# Assign a dynamic Vuejs value to css

Tags: css, vue.js

I have the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6cu295sn/1/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cct',
  lang: {           
    myText: "my text is",
  }
});
```

```css
.myCSS::after{
  content: {{lang.myText}}; //this does not output anything
}
```

I am trying to assign the Vuejs dynamic value to the CSS (content), please can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a css variable, to apply it as content of your pseudo class, as below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cct',
  data () {
    return {
      lang: "my text is"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.myCSS {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myCSS::after {
  content: var(--myText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="cct">
  <input v-model="lang">
  <div class="myCSS" :style="`--myText: '${lang}'`"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer and it's exactly what the OP is after. It's clear they want to use CSS `content`. The only thing I'd add is perhaps using a fallback to `attr()` if IE11 support is required